# Is the intersection of $k \geq 3$ graphic matroids in P?

Tags: complexity-theory, matroids

It is known that intersection of three general matroids is NP-hard ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid_intersection)), which is done via reduction from Hamiltonian cycle. The reduction uses one graphic matroid and two connectivity matroids.

A special case of a problem I am working on can be solved by intersection multiple graphic matroids, but I haven't been able to find, whether this problem is in P. Is it known? Can someone refer me to a paper or something?

Comment: suggest asking on [cstheory.se]. one possible approach is through the independent set problem which has many NP complete variants.

Comment: Also posted on TCS.SE: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/38202/5038.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.  @vzn, in the future, if you suggest another site, could you remind people not to cross-post?  You can suggest they delete the copy here before posting elsewhere, or flag their question for migration and wait.  That will help provide a better experience for them. Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was cross-posted on TCS.SE.

Comment: I agree with the closing and sorry for the duplication.